# Prevent Multiple Clicks in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I am creating a dynamic quiz and I need to prevent multiple clicks on my 'next' button.  In the click function I tried to an `if` condition to prevent multiple clicks.  Not sure why it doesn't work.  Would greatly appreciate some help.

```
var nextButton= $('<button/>', {
    text: 'Next', 
    id: 'nextButton',
    click: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if($("#container").filter(':animated').length>0) {
                  return false;
            }

        /* rest of code*/
     }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tCkuF/9/) is the code as it appears my JSFiddle of my application

Bonus Question:  I was told `event.preventDefault()` is good practice.  Is this true?  If so, why?

Update:  **The JSFiddle line #** where the code above **is line 81** in case you want to mess around with the code without digging through it all.

Comment: preventDefault is good practice because it stops href in anchor tags from changing your location!

Comment: Thanks Neil, I suppose I gotta go back to the books for a little more foundational stuff on it

Comment: I found out why. Check out my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var nextButton= $('<button/>', {
    text: 'Next', 
    id: 'nextButton',
    click: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if($("#insideContainer").filter(':animated').length>0) {
                  return false;
            }

        /* rest of code*/

     }
});
```

I found out why. You're checking against the wrong element. It should be `#insideContainer`
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tCkuF/10/)

Comment: Khanh TO, I like this idea.  When I try this it does not work... Any further suggestions?

Comment: post your updated code in the question. This solution must work. Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/uvuwup/2/edit)

Comment: @KhanhTO, thanks for the demo.  I wasn't properly syntaxing my setTimeout(function...  But I got it working now

Comment: @passionateCoder: thank you for your suggested edit. But it seems not solve the problem and i rejected it. Anyway, thank you very much

Comment: @KhanhTO , THANKS a bunch!  Foolish of me to label my elements like this... probably gonna change them now

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$("#id or .class").one("click",function(){
  // your activity
});
```

**Description:**

The one() method attaches one or more event handlers for the selected elements, and specifies a function to run when the event occurs.

When using the one() method, the event handler function is only run ONCE for each element.

Comment: You won't be able to click again.

Comment: its right if you use .one method ...it will not allow to click again........it's trigger only one time

Comment: but OP **wants** the button to be clickable again after a while.

Comment: Exactly as passionateCoder said, I need to be able to click it again after the next set of radios/answerChoices have been loaded

Comment: use class concept...hope this will give idea..    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked'))
    {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      alert("dd"); // this is clicked once, do something here
    }

Comment: @PankajKumarJha, thanks for the help, I am not confident using class concepts, but appreciate your input anyway

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this to use `timeStamp` property of event like this to gap some time between multiple clicks:

```
var a = $("a"),
    stopClick = 0;


a.on("click", function(e) {
  if(e.timeStamp - stopClick > 300) { // give 300ms gap between clicks
     // logic here

    stopClick = e.timeStamp; // new timestamp given
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to prevent multiple clicks.

**Desc:** Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

Comment: How does this prevent the click from being called more than once? Doesn't this stop the even bubbling up the dom?

Comment: @Neil you're right, this stops the event bubbling up the DOM and also keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed.

Comment: @user1671639 That did not seem to do the trick when I updated my code.